# GraphViz: trouble with grid layout using pos attribute

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to align this graph, whose purpose is to show the results of sorting.
I need a general solution.
The dot file is generated, so I can't use hand tweaking.

I've tried `pos`, `pos` with `!`, `dot -n`, `dot -Kneato`, `dot -Kfdp`, and other things.

Here is the source (laid out for human grokkability):

```
digraph x {
  rankdir=LR

   11 [pos="1,1"]   21 [pos="2,1"]   31 [pos="3,1"]   41 [pos="4,1"]
   12 [pos="1,2"]   22 [pos="2,2"]   32 [pos="3,2"]   42 [pos="4,2"]
   13 [pos="1,3"]   23 [pos="2,3"]   33 [pos="3,3"]
   14 [pos="1,4"]   24 [pos="2,4"]

   11:e ->  21:w    21:e ->  31:w    31:e ->  41:w
   12:e ->  22:w    22:e ->  32:w    32:e ->  42:w
                    22:e ->  31:w
#                                                     41:e ->  21:w
#                                                     41:e ->  22:w 
#  12:e ->  12:w
#                                    32:e ->  32:w

   13:e ->  23:w    23:e ->  33:w
   14:e ->  24:w
#  13:e ->  14:w
#  14:e ->  13:w
#                   23:e ->  24:w
#                   24:e ->  23:w
}
```

In the first rendering, you'll see essentially how it should look (except for the shuffled row order).
Later renderings, which will include cyclic edges, should retain this basic layout.

`dot -Tpng -o test.png test.dot`:

[image]

Now some renderings after uncommenting the cyclic edges.

`dot -Tpng -o test.png test.dot`:

[image]

`dot -Kneato -Tpng -o test.png test.dot`:

[image]

`dot -Kfdp -Tpng -o test.png test.dot`:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you rule out "hand tweaking", what kind of solution do you expect?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with `pos`? Is there some other systematic way to force nodes into a grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using `pos` as in my experience (confirmed by your attempts), it does not work well with the `dot` engine, and with `neato` and others I have never been able to produce something like a grid layout.

Three general steps to get closer with `dot`:

- align the nodes *vertically* with `rank = same`
- align the nodes *horizontally* using `weight = 10` (or any other arbitrary number that works)
- add invisible vertical struts as necessary (here 14 -> 12)
- make sure that you point the edges following the established hierarchy, meaning explicitly using `dir = back` where appropriate

My shot at your situation:

```
digraph 
{
    rankdir = LR;

    {rank = same; 14 -> 13 -> 12 -> 11[ style = invis ] }
    {rank = same; 24 -> 23 -> 22 -> 21[ style = invis ] }
    {rank = same; 33 -> 32 -> 31[ style = invis ] }
    {rank = same; 42 -> 41[ style = invis ] }

    14 -> 24[ weight = 10 ];
    13 -> 23 -> 33[ weight = 10 ];
    12 -> 22 -> 32 -> 42[ weight = 10 ];
    11 -> 21 -> 31 -> 41[ weight = 10 ];

    22:e -> 31:w;

    12:e -> 12:w
    32:e -> 32:w

    21:se ->  41:sw[ dir = back ];
    22:se ->  41:sw[ dir = back ];

    14 -> 12    [ color = red ];
    14:w -> 13:w
    13:e -> 14:e[ dir = back ];

    24:w -> 23:w
    23:e -> 24:e[ dir = back ];
}
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: I note that you added `14:w -> 12:w` to keep it from getting messy. I edited the text, but if you accept the edit, it will need a new rendering.

Comment: Done - sorry, this was just a typo but yes, the effect was significant. I'm sure you have tried without the red edge - it looks messier but still OK in my view, I think it really depends upon how much "tweaking" you can do.

Comment: Try it out on GraphVizFiddle [here](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/2.1.2/).